# map emitted keys change inside reducer/combiner

Tags: hadoop

I need to do two separate matrix multiplications (S*A and P*A) inside my mappers and emit the results of both. I know i can do that easily with two mapreduce job, but inorder to save running time I need to do them in one job. So what I do is that after doing both multiplications I put both of outputs in context object, but with different keys so that I can distinguish them inside reducer:

```
LongWritable One = new LongWritable();
One.set(1);
context.write(One, partialSA);
LongWritable two = new LongWritable();
two.set(2);
context.write(two, partialPA);
```

In reduce, I just need to add all partialSA matrices together and add all partialPA matrices together too. The problem is that If I use combiner, the emitted keys I receive inside combiner are 0 and 1 instead of 1 and two!!! And if i dont use combiner, inside reducer I receive 0 and 1 as keys instead of 1 and 2.

Why is this happening? what is the problem?

Here is the exact cleanup function of my mapper:

```
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
  LongWritable one = new LongWritable();
  one.set(1);
  LongWritable two = new LongWritable();
  two.set(2)
  context.write(one, partialSA);
  context.write(two, partialPA);
}
```

Here is the reducer() code:

```
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<MatrixWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{         
  System.out.println("*** In reduce() **** "+key.get());
  Iterator<MatrixWritable> itr = values.iterator();

  if(key.get() == 1){
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      SA.addMatrices(itr.next());
    }
  }else if(key.get() == 2){
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      PA.addMatrices(itr.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a code snippet from your mapper and reducer, please? What happens if you don't use a reducer or combiner? I guess the problem is in the mapper...

Comment: This is the cleanup function of mapper:                             public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

  LongWritable one = new LongWritable();
  one.set(1);
  LongWritable two = new LongWritable();
  two.set(2)
  context.write(one, partialSA);
  context.write(two, partialPA);
}                                                                      actually I dont need combiner at all, but not using combiner will not solve the problem, because again in reducer I receive the value of key as 0 and 1. any thoughts?

Comment: I just put the snippet of my cleanup function inside my question, this way it looks neater.

Comment: Ok. I just meant for debugging reasons to remove the reducer and see the output of the mapper. Do you use the `get()` method of `LongWritable` to see the numeric values?

Comment: Can you also post a code snippet of the reducer?

Comment: I added the reducer code as well